# Por que puedo acceder a la propiedad tres si no la puse en el super?

Tags: javascript, clase, atributos

Si la funcion super es para poder utilizar las variables de la clase padre, porque es que puedo acceder a la variable tres, que no inclui en el super.

```
    class miClaseUno {
        constructor(nombre, apellido) {
            this.uno = nombre;
            this.dos = apellido;
            **this.tres = "Hola a todos"**
        };
    
        miMetodoUno() {
            return this.uno;
        };
    
        miMetodoDos(parametroUno, parametroDos) {
            document.write(
                "El parametro UNO es: " + parametroUno +
                "<br> El parametro DOS es: " + parametroDos
            );
    
    
        };
    };
    
    class miClaseDos extends miClaseUno {
        constructor(uno, dos, cuarto) {
            **super(uno, dos);** //Toma las dos variables de la clase que esta heredando
            this.cuatro = cuarto;
        };
    
    };
    
    
    
    var ObjetoTres = new miClaseDos("Miguel", "Martinez", 55);
    **document.write(ObjetoTres.tres);**
```

La parte del codigo que requiere de atencion para resolver mi duda esta encerrada en asteriscos, espero puedan ayudarme.
Pueden contestar con tecnisismos, Estoy retomando la POO ya que tengo a;os sin programar, pero puedo entender a la perfeccion si me explican. MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: La propiedad `tres` se está creando con un valor constante: `"Hola a todos"`. No necesita ningún parámetro para que sea creado.

Answer (score 1):

`extends` "extiende" la clase, pero `super` crea una instancia del padre. Por lo que podemos acceder a todo el objeto padre. **Ademas**, la palabra clave `super` se usa para llamar metodos estáticos. Creo que de ahi viene la confusión.

```js
class Rectangulo {
  constructor(alto, ancho) {
    this.alto = alto;
    this.ancho = ancho;    
  }
  
  area() {
    return this.alto * this.ancho;
  }
  
  nombre(algo){
  
    return "Este es un método estático "+algo
  
  }
  
}

class Cubo extends Rectangulo {
  constructor(largoSegmento) {
    super(largoSegmento, largoSegmento);// <-- Creamos un instancia
    this.nombre2 = super.nombre("Lo llamamos del hijo");// llamamos a metodos de la clase padre dentro del hijo
  }
}

const a = new Cubo(20)

console.log(a.area())// <-- Imposible sin instancia de Rectangulo
console.log(a.nombre("Lo llamamos como si fuera Cubo"))// <-- Método obtenido por extends, hereda los métodos
console.log(a.nombre2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como sabrás Javascript no sigue las normas clásicas de la POO, usa otro método para implementar las herencias. Concretamente prototype: todo lo que asignes a prototype es heredado. Cada objeto lleva adosada una cadena de prototypes.
No te dejes confundir por la expresión class, en el fondo es una manera de facilitar la escritura de código, realmente no es más que la declaración function con los prototype incorporados.
En este caso al crear la "clase" miClaseDos con extends miCLaseUno, los objetos instanciados de esta clase (miClaseDos) heredan la propiedad "**tres**" (el prototype está implicito). por el uso de **extends**.
Más detalle: Al buscar **ObjetoTres.tres** como no se encuentra en su constructor (**miClaseDos**), se acude al **prototpye** de éste y ahí se encuentra **miClaseUno** que si tiene la propiedad tres, y la lee.
Un poco lioso pero en realidad es muy simple, como todo Javascript. La clave es la cadena de prototype.
Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: El comportamiento en este caso sería igual en Java o cualquier otro lenguaje orientado a objetos: los atributos de la clase padre existen implícitamente en las clases hijas